# auto complete results postion - IE8 issue

Tags: internet-explorer-8, autocomplete, ajaxtags

We are using java **ajaxtags** as a library to populate **auto complete** values for textbox. It is working perfectly in most of the browsers (Firefox, ie6, ie7 etc...).

But **in case of IE8** the position of **auto complete results** are **not linked** with the actual textbox, instead it is **shifted towards down**. It is happening **only in IE8**.

Please suggest a solution to resolve this issue and to be able to the display auto complete results in a proper way.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the **solution** myself...

In **control.js** file I have added the following condition to get it worked

```
if(!update.style.position || update.style.position=='absolute') {
   update.style.position = 'absolute';
```

> ```
> // Adding the following condtion will fix the issue with IE8
>   if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE')>0) {
>      update.style.display = 'inline';
>   }
> ```

```
   Position.clone(element, update, {setHeight: false, offsetTop: element.offsetHeight});
}
```